# If field exists, take next field

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

I am working on a small custom admin in Wordpress where users can upload 5 images.

I upload the images to a Wordpress library and then save the image url in a custom field from a post.

I want to make something that if the users uploads an image and for example the first and second fields are already storing an image url the script takes the next field.

I have this now but it does not work:

Before this script I have the file upload and this script works only with a form submit of course.

Using `current_user_company()` I get the ID of the user's post. (this is a custom made function)

```
$company_images = range( 0, 6 );
unset( $company_images[0] );


    $field = 1;
    foreach ( $company_images as $key => $value ) {
        if( get_post_meta( current_user_company( 'ID' ), 'company_image_' . $field, true ) ) {
            $field++;
            $image_field = update_post_meta( current_user_company( 'ID' ), 'company_image_' . $field, $attachment_url );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking for only one field, i.e.:

If the user has already used fields 1-3, you want to use 4, so in your code:

```
$field = 1;
foreach ( $company_images as $key => $value ) {
    //this while loop will iterate through every used field        
    while( get_post_meta( current_user_company( 'ID' ), 'company_image_' . $field, true ) ) 
        $field++;
    //when the program reaches this point, $field should be 4 in our example 
    $image_field = update_post_meta( current_user_company( 'ID' ), 'company_image_' . $field, $attachment_url );
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried your code but it uploads the image to all the fields. I think we need a break if the script found the right field?

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but that is not what I mean. I need a break if for example 1-2 are used so the right field is 3. And after that the script needs to stop so fields 4 and 5 stay empty.